# É possível integrar o express-validator com o multer?

Tags: node.js, express.js, validação, multer

Estou desenvolvendo uma API para estudo e nessa API tenho a funcionalidade de adicionar um veículo, no qual eu recupero os dados passados pelo usuário e uma imagem. Porém como eu estou utilizando a ***express-validator***, toda vez que ela apresenta um erro de validação, o upload da imagem acontece do mesmo jeito. Gostaria de saber se é possível eu adicionar uma condição ou algo do tipo para que o upload seja realizado somente quando não ocorrer nenhum erro de validação.

Estou utilizando a ***express-validator*** para a validação dos dados e o ***multer*** como middleware para o upload das imagens.

Trecho do código que gostaria de saber se é possivel adicionar uma condição para o upload:

```
// Adiciona um novo veiculo
app.post("/AdicionarVeiculo", [upload.single("image"), regrasValidacao], (req, res) => {

  // Guarda os erros de validação
  const validationErros = validationResult(req);

  // Verifica se ocorreu algum erro
  if (!validationErros.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      errors: validationErros.array()
    });
  }

  const dados = { ...req.body,
    imagem: req.file.path
  };

  console.log(dados);

  Veiculos.adicionarVeiculo(dados, res);
});
```

Comment: Infelizmente não existe uma forma decente de se fazer validação antes do upload com _multer_. Ele até oferece um método `fileFilter` para verificacao de tipo de arquivo, mas fazer validação de outros campos seria exagerar o propósito dessa função. O seu problema é mais voltado para o upload no caso de erro, pode se sugerir uma alternativa como excluir o arquivo em caso de erro de validacao?

Comment: Bem pensado, fiz isso de excluir a imagem na qual acabei de fazer upload caso ocorra algum erro de validação e deu certo! muito obrigado!